# What is this Excel help field and can it be edited?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, office365, gui

- What is this thing called?
- Can I as a developer add things to it manually, e.g. help for a custom-made add-in?
- Is there an API to control it programmatically?

It's a kind of help search field. The convenient thing is that can be accessed by the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> keyboard shortcut, and that it remembers your last action.

Reason I'm asking: Would be a super convenient way for my users to access my add-in's functionality and help.

[image]

Search for a functionality:

[image]

Later, remembers last action, enabling quick and easy access via keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, but Stack Overflow might be a better site for it since you're asking for developer expertise.  That site probably has a bigger concentration of people who may have worked with that.

Comment: @fixer1234 This would probably get closed on Stack Overflow as too broad / off-topic. I asked here because, in the first instance, I'm looking for a general answer about what the thing is called, and whether it can be edited (via the GUI or otherwise). Once I get that, then I can do some digging and come up with a proper SO question that is about programming.

Comment: Maybe record a macro accessing that box, and look at the VBA?